# Kernel block device - Falling in deadlock using spinlock

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, deadlock, spinlock, block-device

I just implemented a virtual block device and I would like to play with it in order to explore how linux kernel handles block devices.

My device is just a memory zone divided in two 512 bytes sectors.

I'm using a global structure to store device informations:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t hard_sector_size;        // Size of a device sector
    uint32_t sector_number;           // Number of sector on device
    uint32_t size;                    // Total size of virtual device in bytes
    uint8_t* data;                    // Device memory buffer
    spinlock_t device_lock;           // Device structure access spinlock
    struct request_queue *queue;      // Device request queue
    struct gendisk *gendisk;          // Device "disk" representation
    int major;                        // Device major number attributed by kernel
    int minor;                        // Device minor number fixed at initialization
    uint32_t r_users;                 // Number of read access
    uint32_t w_users;                 // Number of write access
}blk_mod_t;

blk_mod_t self;

[...]
```

Now I would like to protect this structure against concurrent access. To do so I'm using the `device_lock` field.
If the lock is taken, the structure is being updated so I should wait until finished.
If it's not taken, I can access the structure fields.

Right now I'm using this spinlock only into the three following functions

```
static int block_mod_open(struct block_device *bdev, fmode_t mode)
{
    access_mode_t access_mode;
    DEBUG("Entering open function\n");

    if((mode & FMODE_READ) && (mode & FMODE_WRITE))
    {
        NOTICE("Oppened in read/write mode\n");
        mode = ACCESS_RW;
    }
    else if(mode & FMODE_READ)
    {
        NOTICE("Oppened in read only mode\n");
        mode = ACCESS_RONLY;
    }
    else if(mode & FMODE_WRITE)
    {
        NOTICE("Oppened in write only mode\n");
        mode = ACCESS_WONLY;
    }

    DEBUG("<--\n");
    spin_lock(&self.device_lock);

    if(ACCESS_RW == access_mode)
    {
        self.r_users++;
        self.w_users++;
    }
    else if(ACCESS_RONLY == access_mode)
    {
        self.r_users++;
    }
    else
    {
        self.w_users++;
    }
    NOTICE("Read access: %d\tWrite access: %d\n", self.r_users, self.w_users);

    DEBUG("-->\n");
    spin_unlock(&self.device_lock);

    DEBUG("Exiting open function\n");
    return 0;
}

static void block_mod_release(struct gendisk *disk, fmode_t mode)
{
    access_mode_t access_mode;
    DEBUG("Entering release function\n");

    if((mode & FMODE_READ) && (mode & FMODE_WRITE))
    {
        NOTICE("Closed read/write mode\n");
        mode = ACCESS_RW;
    }
    else if(mode & FMODE_READ)
    {
        NOTICE("Closed read only mode\n");
        mode = ACCESS_RONLY;
    }
    else if(mode & FMODE_WRITE)
    {
        NOTICE("Closed write only mode\n");
        mode = ACCESS_WONLY;
    }

    DEBUG("<--\n");
    spin_lock(&self.device_lock);

    if(ACCESS_RW == access_mode)
    {
        self.r_users--;
        self.w_users--;
    }
    else if(ACCESS_RONLY == access_mode)
    {
        self.r_users--;
    }
    else
    {
        self.w_users--;
    }
    NOTICE("Read access: %d\tWrite access: %d\n", self.r_users, self.w_users);

    DEBUG("-->\n");
    spin_unlock(&self.device_lock);

    DEBUG("Exiting release function\n");
    return;
}

static void block_mod_transfer(unsigned long sector, unsigned long nsect, char *buffer, int write)
{
    unsigned long offset = sector*KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE;
    unsigned long nbytes = nsect*KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE;
    DEBUG("Entering transfer function\n");
    DEBUG("<--\n");
    spin_lock(&self.device_lock);

    if((offset + nbytes) > self.size) {
        WARNING("Beyond-end write (%ld %ld)\n", offset, nbytes);
        spin_unlock(&self.device_lock);
        return;
    }
    if(write)
    {
        NOTICE("Writing to device\n");
        memcpy(self.data + offset, buffer, nbytes);
    }
    else
    {
        NOTICE("Reading from device\n");
        memcpy(buffer, self.data + offset, nbytes);
    }

    DEBUG("-->\n");
    spin_unlock(&self.device_lock);
    DEBUG("Exiting transfer function\n");
}
```

I'm treating requests with the following function

```
static void block_mod_request(struct request_queue *queue)
{
    DEBUG("Entering request function\n");
    struct request *request;

    while(NULL != (request = blk_fetch_request(queue)))
    {
        blk_mod_t *self = request->rq_disk->private_data;
        // Check if request is a filesystem request (i.e. moves block of data)
        if(REQ_TYPE_FS != request->cmd_type)
        {
            // Close request with unsuccessful status
            WARNING("Skip non-fs request\n");
            __blk_end_request_cur(request, -EIO);
            continue;
        }
        // Treat request
        block_mod_transfer(blk_rq_pos(request), blk_rq_cur_sectors(request), bio_data(request->bio), rq_data_dir(request));
        // Close request with successful status
        __blk_end_request_cur(request, 0);
    }

    DEBUG("Exiting request function\n");
    return;
}
```

When I load the module nothing special happens. However if I try to read from it I'm falling in deadlock as my system doesn't answer anymore and I have to reboot.

Here is the output:

```
root@PC325:~# echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
root@PC325:~# insmod block_mod.ko 
[   64.546791] block_mod: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   64.548197] block_mod: module license '(c) Test license' taints kernel.
[   64.549951] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   64.552816] Inserting module 'blk_mod_test'
[   64.554085] Got major number : '254'
[   64.554940] Data allocated (size = 1024)
[   64.557378] Request queue initialized
[   64.558178] Sent hard sector size to request queue
[   64.559188] Gendisk allocated
[   64.559817] Gendisk filled
[   64.560416] Gendisk capacity set
[   64.563285] Gendisk added
root@PC325:~# [   64.565280] Entering open function
[   64.566035] Oppened in read only mode
[   64.566773] <--
[   64.567138] Read access: 1   Write access: 0
[   64.567977] -->
[   64.568342] Exiting open function
[   64.571080] Entering release function
[   64.571855] Closed read only mode
[   64.572531] <--
[   64.572924] Read access: 0   Write access: 0
[   64.573749] -->
[   64.574116] Exiting release function
root@PC325:~# cat /dev/blkmodtest 
[   78.488228] Entering open function
[   78.488988] Oppened in read only mode
[   78.489733] <--
[   78.490100] Read access: 1   Write access: 0
[   78.490925] -->
[   78.491290] Exiting open function
[   78.492026] Entering request function
[   78.492743] Entering transfer function
[   78.493469] <--
-------------- DEADLOCK HERE --------------
```

***UPDATE:*** Add init and exit functions

```
static int __init block_mod_init(void)
{
    char* message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int i;

    INFO("Inserting module '%s'\n", MODULE_NAME);

    // Initialize driver data structure
    memset(&self, 0, sizeof(blk_mod_t));
    self.hard_sector_size = DEVICE_HARD_SECTOR_SIZE;
    self.sector_number = DEVICE_SECTOR_NUMBER;
    self.size = self.sector_number*self.hard_sector_size;
    self.minor = 1;

    // Get a major number from kernel
    if(0 > (self.major = register_blkdev(self.major, MODULE_NAME)))
    {
        ERROR("Unable to get major number for '%s'\n", MODULE_NAME);
        unregister_blkdev(self.major, MODULE_NAME);
        return -1;
    }
    DEBUG("Got major number : '%d'\n", self.major);

    // Allocate data space
    if(NULL == (self.data = vmalloc(self.size)))
    {
        ERROR("Unable to allocate memory for '%s'\n", MODULE_NAME);
        unregister_blkdev(self.major, MODULE_NAME);
        return -2;
    }
    for(i=0;i<self.size;i++)
    {
        self.data[i] = message[i%strlen(message)];
    }
    spin_lock_init(&self.device_lock);
    DEBUG("Data allocated (size = %d)\n", self.size);

    // Allocate the request queue
    if(NULL == (self.queue = blk_init_queue(block_mod_request, &self.device_lock)))
    {
        ERROR("Unable to initialize request queue for '%s'\n", MODULE_NAME);
        vfree(self.data);
        unregister_blkdev(self.major, MODULE_NAME);
        return -3;
    }
    DEBUG("Request queue initialized\n");

    // Send device hard sector size to request queue
    blk_queue_logical_block_size(self.queue, self.hard_sector_size);
    self.queue->queuedata = &self;
    DEBUG("Sent hard sector size to request queue\n");

    // Allocate the gendisk structure
    if(NULL == (self.gendisk = alloc_disk(self.minor)))
    {
        ERROR("Unable to initialize gendisk for '%s'\n", MODULE_NAME);
        blk_cleanup_queue(self.queue);
        vfree(self.data);
        unregister_blkdev(self.major, MODULE_NAME);
        return -4;
    }
    DEBUG("Gendisk allocated\n");

    // Fill gendisk structure
    self.gendisk->major = self.major;
    self.gendisk->first_minor = self.minor;
    self.gendisk->fops = &self_ops;
    self.gendisk->queue = self.queue;
    self.gendisk->private_data = &self;
    snprintf(self.gendisk->disk_name, 32, "blkmodtest");
    DEBUG("Gendisk filled\n");
    set_capacity(self.gendisk, self.sector_number*(self.hard_sector_size/KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE));
    DEBUG("Gendisk capacity set\n");
    add_disk(self.gendisk);
    DEBUG("Gendisk added\n");

    return 0;
}

static void __exit block_mod_cleanup(void)
{
    del_gendisk(self.gendisk);
    put_disk(self.gendisk);
    blk_cleanup_queue(self.queue);
    vfree(self.data);
    unregister_blkdev(self.major, MODULE_NAME);

    INFO("Removing module '%s'\n", MODULE_NAME);
    return;
}
```

***UPDATE:*** Add macro and enum definitions

```
#define MODULE_NAME                    "blk_mod_test"
#define KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE             512
#define DEVICE_HARD_SECTOR_SIZE        512
#define DEVICE_SECTOR_NUMBER           2

typedef enum
{
    ACCESS_RONLY = 0,
    ACCESS_WONLY = 1,
    ACCESS_RW    = 2,
}access_mode_t;
```

What I don't understand is that the spinlock has been released (at end of `block_mod_open`) before I try to lock it into `block_mod_transfer`.

So I don't understand why kernel is falling in deadlock when the spinlock seems to be available to be taken.

**Why am I falling in deadlock in this case? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Please post [at least] your module load function. I have a suspicion but would need to see more

Comment: I'm not sure exactly the cause, but the line `blk_mod_t *self = request->rq_disk->private_data;` looks suspicious in any case.

Comment: @CraigEstey I have added both init and exit functions. Don't hesitate if you need more (almost everything is here tough).

Comment: @JoshuaHannah I never use this field of the request queue. I think I have added this to match tutorials I have seen but I never use it

Comment: What are your values for (e.g.) `DEVICE_HARD_SECTOR_SIZE` et. al? I'm still looking at your driver. While you're waiting, here's a decent refererence/tutorial: https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch16.pdf Based on the traces, a quick guess is that it's _not_ the spinlock, but the `memcpy` [silently freezes system] and this happens before the trace message comes out. Add a debug msg after spinlock but _before_ `memcpy` to further narrow. Also, try commenting out the `memcpy`s to see if you survive

Comment: @CraigEstey I do have messages before `memcpy` (i.e. `NOTICE(...)`). I've tried with `memcpy` commented out and a message just after the call to `spin_lock()` but still the same behaviour. And btw LDD3 is the book I'm currently using ;) (I have only read chapters 5 and 16 yet).

Comment: The request function _may_ be being called from interrupt context. Use `spin_trylock` to verify (if it comes back false), you are stacking on the same cpu. Also, look at the return from `in_interrupt()`. If so, you'll need to replace `spin_lock` in [at least] the other two places with `unsigned long flags = spin_lock_irqsave(...)` [and replace the unlocks with the `*_irqrestore` versions]. Using the irq versions can't hurt [just a little less performance if they're not necessary]

Comment: I have tried using `in_interrupt()` macro and I'm never in interrupt context (always returns 0). However trying to take the lock with `spin_trylock` into `block_mod_transfer` function always fails but succeed into `block_mod_open` and `block_mod_release` functions. Btw thanks for your help I'm would not have checked it by myself

Comment: `blk_fetch_request` expects that the queue's lock is held. It has an assert for that [which may be disabled due to the kernel taint re. lock debug]. See `lockdep.h` and do your own check in your request function before entering.

Comment: @CraigEstey I have checked using `spin_is_locked(queue->queue_lock)` and it seems that the losk is already held before entering `blk_fetch_request` as the function returns 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CraigEstey's comments I have finally found that the problem came from the fact that the request queue was initialized with the same spinlock than my device structure.

```
// Allocate the request queue
if(NULL == (self.queue = blk_init_queue(block_mod_request, &self.device_lock)))
{
    ERROR("Unable to initialize request queue for '%s'\n", MODULE_NAME);
    vfree(self.data);
    unregister_blkdev(self.major, MODULE_NAME);
    return -3;
}
```

So when the request queue's callback function (i.e. `block_mod_request`) is called, the spinlock is already held and I'm falling in deadlock.